# Python Two Integer Loop, +1 to A until A=B

Tags: python, loops, integer

I need help creating a loop which will ask the user for two numbers in python, (one larger than the other), and then keep adding 1 to the small number, until the small number is equal to the large number.

During this, I need it to print out the numbers at the same time.

**Background :** I am very new to python, and this is the last step in a programming class I am apart of, I have completed 4 tasks, which have been quite simple, but this is the remaining one.

**Example :** Please enter a small number : 5
          Please enter a large number : 10
          5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10

**How I would like this to work?**

```
var_small = int(raw_input("Please enter a small number : "))
var_large = int(raw_input("Please enter a large number : "))

if var_small > var_large:
print "Try two other numbers, remember that the small number comes first!"
 #Here I would re-run the loop
elif var_small < var_large:
var_small +1 until = var_large
```

I'm sorry for such a noob question, I hope I get a response.

Answer (score 2):

You have to combine your assignment to var_small and var_large with a while loop

```
var_small = int(raw_input("Please enter a small number : "))
var_large = int(raw_input("Please enter a large number : "))

while var_small > var_large:
    print "Try two other numbers, remember that the small number comes first!"
    var_small = int(raw_input("Please enter a small number : "))
    var_large = int(raw_input("Please enter a large number : "))

while var_small != var_large:
    var_small += 1
    print var_small, var_large
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> var_small = 5
>>> var_large = 10
>>> range(var_small, var_large + 1)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

---

I guess you're looking for a "rawer" way. Well a [`while`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while)-loop looks like it would suit you:

```
>>> while var_small <= var_large:
...     print var_small
...     var_small += 1
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: @JonClements Alright, I added an approach using a `while`-loop

Answer (score 0):

The following code does not require the input statements to be repeated and presents the output as you request (on a single line):

```py
# Initialize variables.
var_small = 0
var_large = 0

while var_small >= var_large:
    var_small = int(raw_input("Please enter a small number : "))
    var_large = int(raw_input("Please enter a large number : "))

    # Need to try this again ?
    if var_small >= var_large:
        print "Try two other numbers, remember that the small number comes first!"

# Output loop
while var_small != var_large:
    # Mind the , at the end to avoid a newline
    print "%d, " % var_small,
    var_small = var_small + 1

# Also print the last value and a newline
print var_large
```